# MySQL data time query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my MySQL Query but despite the amount of searching I can't seem to find an answer.

I have a table that records data for something. It gets updated every 2 minutes by a cron job. When the data is intially input into the table the 'date' field is as follows:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

And then every time it gets updated it the NOW() function is used and so outputs as follows:

```
2011-07-07 15:44:02
```

Then when the object being recorded goes offline the data then gets filed away in a different table. The problem is that I cannot seem to write a successful query to select rows where the 'date' field has not been updated for 10 minutes.

The current query I have is below; (it seems to file the row but only after several hours. I have checked the time zone as I suspected that is likely to be causing the problem however, the NOW() query is run from the same PHP file as the query below, so that can't be the problem.

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE check_active = '1' AND check_recorded = '0' AND takeoff = '1' AND callsign != '' AND `date` < DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 10 MINUTE )
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're doing all the date updating/generating in MySQL, then timezones won't enter it. It'd only be if you were producing a date in PHP and using it in MySQL (or vice versa) that timezones would be a concern.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of other criteria in your WHERE condition... I would start with the date first to see how many records ARE found, then gradually add each "AND" criteria to see where it finally chokes...

```
SELECT * 
   FROM data 
   WHERE `date` < DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 10 MINUTE )
```

THEN, add the others... one at a time...

```
     AND check_active = '1' 
     AND check_recorded = '0' 
     AND takeoff = '1' 
     AND callsign != ''
```

It could completely be legit that you have no records available if all "objects" are still being updated within the 2 minute interval, and thus none of them are beyond the 10 minute cycle your are looking for "stale/offline" activity.

Answer (score 0):

First, should you be addressing your field `date` as following: date(`date`) < .... to be able to calculate?

Second, you're are inserting every 2 minutes and if that doesn't happen you want to get output from this query? does that describe your needs?